# How can I Wait for Arrays of Tasks of different Types?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a pretty simple looking problem, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Given I have several arrays of tasks of different types e.g.

```
Task<Dog>[] dogTasks = GetDogTasks();
Task<Cat>[] catTasks = GetCatTasks();
Task<Fish>[] fishTasks = GetFishTasks();
```

What would be the best way to `WaitAll()` for these tasks?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I get the error `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(params System.Threading.Tasks.Task[])' has some invalid arguments` - `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object>[]' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'` for each of the values I try to wait for.

Comment: Sorry, missed it was an array. See the duplicate to see how to construct a new array of all tasks.

Comment: No worries. I tried the other solution already - it doesn't work for differing types. My question is not a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx) should solve your problem. You have arrays of tasks so you should create one array from them:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.AddRange(dogTasks);
tasks.AddRange(catTasks);
tasks.AddRange(fishTasks);
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: Updated. Create one array from them

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @SergiiZhevzhyk